# Where does the little triangle icon of sortable JTable header come from?

Tags: java, swing

I am writting a customized component which need to use the little triangle icon of sortable JTable header. Maybe it's not really an icon file but a graphics painted by some class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the sort icon comes from the look and feel. For example, in the Windows look and feel, the `WindowsTableHeaderUI` looks up the following to draw the appropriate icon. For ascending:

```
UIManager.getIcon("Table.ascendingSortIcon");
```

For descending:

```
UIManager.getIcon("Table.descendingSortIcon");
```

While the `BasicLookAndFeel` registers a value for these properties (so there is likely to be *something* there if you use a similar call), as @Michael Borgwardt notes (by drawing a conclusion from his answer), there is no guarantee of this since any given look and feel might choose to forego the `UIManager` and draw their own graphics.

Still, it might be worthwhile trying it to see if it does what you want.

Comment: @Ash: Thank you. It do solve my problem! I stick on 'metal' L&F and everything will be OK.

Answer (score 4):

Paiting those would be the job of a subclass of [TableHeaderUI](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/TableHeaderUI.html) specific to the current Look-and-Feel. One L&F might load it from a file while another paints it as a vector graphic.